# 自動デプロイでエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, capistrano

#### 発生している問題

下記の自動デプロイのコマンドを実行すると、エラーが起こります
deploy.rbやCapfileが原因のような気がしますが、変にいじった記憶はないです
何が悪いのでしょうか？

**実行したコマンド**

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

#### エラー内容

```
ERROR: load:defaults has already been invoked and can no longer be modified.
Check that you haven't loaded a Capistrano plugin in deploy.rb or a stage
(e.g. deploy/production.rb) by mistake.
Plugins must be loaded in the Capfile to initialize properly.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
FrozenError: can't modify frozen #<Class:#<Rake::Task:0x00007fdf380bd1b8>>

Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

#### 各ファイルの内容

**deploy.rb**

```
config valid only for current version of Capistrano

lock '3.14.1'


set :application, 'baseball-app'

set :repo_url,  'git@github.com:katou02/baseball-app.git'


set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.5.1'


set :ssh_options, auth_methods: ['publickey'],
                  keys: ['~/.ssh/Rails-app.pem'] 


set :unicorn_pid, -> { "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid" }


set :unicorn_config_path, -> { "#{current_path}/config/unicorn.rb" }
set :keep_releases, 5


after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:restart'
  end
end

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
```

**Capfile**

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.5.2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.7'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'compass-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem "font-awesome-sass"
gem 'ancestry'
# gem 'fog-aws'

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn', '5.4.1'
end
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/295127

Comment: 何のために貼っているのですか？

Comment: 回答される方のために参考になるであろうリンクを張っています。

Comment: 同じ内容を複数のサイトに投稿することを「マルチポスト」と言い、スタックオーバーフローでは特に禁止こそされていませんが、できれば質問文に予め明示してあると回答してくれるかもしれない人に対してより親切になると思います。 / 一方で teratail ではマルチポストは明示するよう [ヘルプに記載されている](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice) のでご注意ください。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: @htb リンクを知らせるコメントは回答者向けには役立つ情報となるかもしれませんが、質問者にとってはそれが何なのか分からない場合があるので、メタの「マルチポストとは？」へのリンクと簡単な説明を添えておくと良いと思います。 / メタでの [マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087) の討議内容も参考にしてください。

Comment: マルチポストを指摘しているわけではなく、参考リンクです。質問者さんに行動を求めてもトラブルのもとです。